# NHibernate one-to-one mapping - full object graph is not saved

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to get NHibernate to save complete object graph in a one-to-one mapping scenario. I have following classes

```
public class Employee : EntityBase
{
    public virtual string EmployeeNumber { get; set; }
    public virtual Address ResidentialAddress {get; set; }
}

public class Address : EntityBase
{
    public virtual string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Postcode { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string Country { get; set; }
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to use one-to-one mapping here so that one employee has only one residential address. My mappings are below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Domain" namespace="Domain">
  <class name="Employee">
    <id name="Id" generator="hilo" />
    <property name="EmployeeNumber" length="10" />
    <one-to-one name="ResidentialAddress" class="Address" property-ref="Employee" cascade="all" />    
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" assembly="Domain" namespace="Domain">
  <class name="Address">
    <id name="Id" generator="hilo" />
    <property name="AddressLine1"/>
    <property name="AddressLine2" />
    <property name="Postcode" />
    <property name="City" />
    <property name="Country" />

    <many-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" unique="true" />

  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am using following code to save an instance of employee object

```
using (var transaction = Session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            id = Session.Save(new Employee
            {
                EmployeeNumber = "123456789",
                ResidentialAddress = new Address
                {
                    AddressLine1 = "Address line 1",
                    AddressLine2 = "Address line 2",
                    Postcode = "postcode",
                    City = "city",
                    Country = "country"
                }
            });
            transaction.Commit();
        }
```

In the above situation, the foreign key on Address back to Employee is always null. But if I change R`ResidentialAddress` property on `Employee` class so that `Employee` property is always populated correctly as below

```
private Address address;
    public virtual Address ResidentialAddress
    {
        get { return address; }
        set
        {
            address = value;

            if (value != null) value.Employee = this;
        }
    }
```

This makes it work perfectly. Why do I have to set `ResidentialAddress.Employee`? Am I missing something in the mappings? Should NHibernate not automatically save the complete object graph (and hence determine proper foreign key values).

The above working code concerns me as it may create a problem when called from NHiberante during loading of entity from database.

Comment: try <many-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" unique="true" inverse="true" /> on the Address mapping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not missing anything.

> **We (developers) should always care about setting both ends of any bidirectional relation.**

When we use `one-to-many` *(without inverse="true")* and without setting the `many-to-one`, we always end up with redundant and unefficient sequence of SQL statements:

- INSERT child record, place NULL into Parent_ID
- UPDATE child record, set the Parent_ID with Parent.ID

This is not suggested: [6.8. Bidirectional Associations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#collections-bidirectional):

> ... The non-inverse side is used to save the in-memory representation to the database. We would get an unneccessary INSERT/UPDATE and probably even a foreign key violation if both would trigger changes! The same is of course also true for bidirectional one-to-many associations...

*So, that is in one-to-many, many-to-one.*

---

*In case of one-to-one*

There is no collection persister in place as discussed above. No man in the middle, which would take care about the other end, and issue "unefficient" INSERT and later UPDATE. NHibernate will use standard entity persisters for `Employee` and `Address`.

Each association end of the relation *(Employee-Address)* has its own persister. These could be triggered in a cascade *(usually good idea to have `<one-to-one  ... cascade="all" />`)*

But each persister needs enough information to create proper INSERT or UPDATE statement. I.e. even C# Address must know about its Employee. The Address persister, will handle INSERT/UPDATE alone, with access to Address instance only.

SUMMARY: We have to set both ends in code.... And that is good practice even if we are not forced *(non inverse child mapping with nullable parent column)*.
 *BTW: once loaded from DB, **we expect** that **NHibernate** will set **both** ends... why should not we do the same?*

Comment: I get your point in inefficient sequence of SQL statements. The most important thing I wanted to know was whether NHibernate is capable of doing bidirectional graph saving for me without I having to set both ends in code. Looks like it is no in case of `one-to-one`. Re:once loaded from DB, we expect that NHibernate will set both ends... why should not we do the same? - I am not sure if my code above for this would create problem when NH loads entities from database.

Comment: I just wanted to encourage you (as much as possible) to assign both sides. Just a few more lines... and set both ends. You can even extend the property setter `ResidentialAddress` of Employee and inside set `value.Employee = this;` ... so your code will remain unchanged, but the relation will be set... Hope this helps ;) And also, your code does not create problem for NHibernate during to loading. The real issue is the INSERT. Both ends must be set.. is the only proper answer.